# odoo 10 report header won't show up

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

i am trying to test report made by my co-worker. it was working properly on his local odoo, and also tested on development server. the result is report header and footer printed properly. 
but when i tried to run it on my local machine to continue the development. the print i did won't show any header nor footer on the report.

i tried to move the header content inside page div tag it show's the content properly but spaced out from header space.
the difference i know between his and my odoo setup is distro used and slight different install method, which listed below

- dev and my co-worker machine use ubuntu meanwhile i used arch
- my co-worker installation was done without using virtualenv while mine used virtualenv

is there anything i missed to setup odoo ? 
installation i've done was following odoo docs installation guide

Edit : 
There also difference in config file which might be the issue .
where i use my short out config file, while my co-worker uses args

Comment: Is only the footer/header missing or the styles (css, less, etc.) also?

Comment: no the site open properly without any missing style, css, etc

Comment: I'm only talking about the generated PDF.

Comment: hmm i cant really tell since i am using custom module,
but it seems using class like col-xs-6, text right working properly for me